# assets table design for rmdbs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created assets (images, pdfs, videos or etc.) table for storing whole assets in my project. For prevent collision I am using guid/uuid. For fetching assets, I join tables like

```
SELECT db_Blogs.*, db_Assets.path FROM db_Blogs INNER JOIN db_Assets ON db_Blogs.guid = db_Assets.guid;
```

**Blogs**

```
id | guid | title | content
```

**Articles**

```
id | guid | title | content
```

**Products**

```
id | guid | name | content
```

**Assets**

```
id | guid | path
```

is this bad design for this issue?

Comment: Why is the `id` not sufficient?

Comment: if I use only id, it will be show all assets for that id. it could be blog.id=1 or product.id = 1. I can't separate these assets. When I use guid that takes global unique id.